# Java jacksonGeneric Serialization

Tags: java, jackson

here I have a generic class like ：

```
  @JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Request")
    public class Request<T> { 
        @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = false,localName="HeaderInfo")
        private HeaderInfo headerInfo; 

        //here I want serialization data use T className
        private T data;
    }
```

for example：
I got

```
 Request<User> request;  to serialization XML like:
    <request><headinfo></headinfo><user></user><request>

 Request<SuperUser> request;  to serialization XML like:
    <request><headinfo></headinfo><SuperUser></SuperUser><request>
```

ect...

Comment: I tried "PropertyNamingStrategy"  but it seems work well with JSON serialization, For XML serialization it seem do not fit this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have solve this promblem
code:

```
public class RequestSerializer extends StdSerializer<Request> {

    public RequestSerializer() {
        super(Request.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Request request, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeObjectField("HeaderInfo", request.getHeaderInfo());
        String name = request.getRequest().getClass().getSimpleName();
        jgen.writeObjectField(name, request.getRequest());
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}



    JacksonXmlModule module = new JacksonXmlModule();
    module.setDefaultUseWrapper(true);
    module.addSerializer(Request.class, new RequestSerializer());
    XmlMapper xml = new XmlMapper(module);
```